# fastest way to delete thousands of rows from postgres db tables  using java

Tags: java, sql

fastest way to delete thousands of rows from  postgres db tables using java.Presently i am using the following code snippet:

```
query = "DELETE FROM NODE WHERE SEQUENCE_NO = " + sequenceNo;
            insertOrDelete(query);




insertOrDelete(String query){
    statement = createStatement();
    numRowUpdated = statement.executeUpdate(query);
    closeStatement(statement);
            }
```

Comment: java relates to javascript like car relates to carpet. Pick one.

Comment: Impossible to help improve delete performance without knowing the target database. Come on! Put some thought in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a Java problem - it's the database.

Make sure there is an index on SEQUENCE_NO. Beyond that, ask the database gurus (depending on the database, there might be things that can improve performance, but in the end it comes all down to database administration: chosing the correct data type for SEQUENCE_NO, keeping meta data up to date etc.).

You probably should add an SQL tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using a single query, then whether it is Java or anything else, I don't think it can get much faster.

Some tips :

- use a PreparedStatement. It may be slightly faster, and it will be cleaner/safer/better
- close the statement in a finally

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider building a statement like

```
DELETE FROM NODE WHERE SEQUENCE_NO In (...);
```

This would do your job in one commit instead of committing several times which would perform better in any case.